# Cut plot_surface at a certain height

Tags: python, matplotlib

Given a surface in `matplotlib`.

Is it possible to plot a slice of it at a certain height `z` and get a "filled" plane with area of interception?

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

x = np.linspace(-5,5)
y = np.linspace(-5,5)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = 3*(1-X)**2*np.exp(-(X**2) - (Y+1)**2) - 10*(X/5 - X**3 - Y**5)*np.exp(-X**2-Y**2) - 1/3*np.exp(-(X+1)**2 - Y**2)

# Create a 3D plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

plot1=ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap='jet')

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
```

How can I get the "area" surface where `z=4`?

I would say that I have to interpolate the meshgrid data at a certain `z`. If so, how can I do that?

Comment: `ax.contour(X, Y, Z, levels=[4], offset=4)`

Comment: If this doesn't answer your question, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77861516/edit) your post and add additional information.  You can also do `contour = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, levels=[4])` with `contour.get_paths()` to obtain the intersection path, which you can use to create a filled polygon, or to calculate the area.